# value of that propertyObject does not match target type in c# (get property value with reflection)

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class that contain this property.

```
public List<string> Messages { get; set; }
```

I want to read value of that property with using reflection.

```
List<string> messages = new List<string>();
PropertyInfo prop = myType.GetProperty("Messages");
var message = prop.GetValue(messages);
```

but I get this error :

> "Object does not match target type."

I used this line:

```
var message = prop.GetValue(messages,null);
```

instead of

```
var message = prop.GetValue(messages);
```

but still I get the same error.

Comment: Why not just "List<string> messages = yourClassObj.Messages;" ?

Comment: i have specific situation that's why I don't want to use that way.

Comment: `GetProperty` does not have an overload that takes a list of strings.  What are you expecting to get as a result?

Comment: so please look at here https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/axt1ctd9(v=vs.100).aspx   you can pass instance of your type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PropertyInfo contains the metadata about your Messages property. You can use that PropertyInfo to get or set the value of that property on some instance of that type. That means that you need to pass an instance of your type, from which you want to read the property `Messages`, into the GetValue call:

```
messages = (List<string>)prop.GetValue(instanceOfMyType);
```

Here is a working example of what you are trying to do:

```
class A
{
    public List<string> Messages { get; set; }

    public static void Test()
    {
        A obj = new A { Messages = new List<string> { "message1", "message2" } };
        PropertyInfo prop = typeof(A).GetProperty("Messages");
        List<string> messages = (List<string>)prop.GetValue(obj);
    }
}
```

Just for the record, this implementation makes no sense in real life, since you can get the value directly through `obj.Messages`

Comment: I passed instance of my type,but still i have error

Comment: If you look at my example, exactly i passed the instance of my type "messages" to the prop.GetValue(messages);                                                          List<string> messages = new List<string>();

Comment: You passed an instance of `List<string>` and not an instance of `myType`. In your example it is not visible what your myType is. I included a working example into my answer. You should be able to reuse it in your code.

Comment: thank you very much .your point is valid point " Just for the record, this implementation makes no sense in real life, since you can get the value directly through obj.Messages" .i modified the title. FYI, i wanted to implement it with reflection for some reason.if i wanted that I mention all reasons, maybe  it could cause confusion for others.